# Python programming to remove certain characters from certain positions in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, class, module, constructor-overloading

Question:

s=

"campaign_5Nu_E_0_87872_shard1.zip"

desired output:
campaign5Nu_E_0_87872shard1.zip

[image]Guys help me........

Answer (score 0):

To remove the single final instance of underscore, we can use a regex replacement:

```py
filename = "campaign_5Nu_E_0_87872_shard1.zip"
output = re.sub(r'_(?!.*_)', '', filename)
print(output)  # campaign_5Nu_E_0_87872shard1.zip
```